# Компоненты Delphi

Tags: delphi

Допустим, у меня есть список из записей, который сохраняется и загружается в/из типизированного файла. Каждая запись - это информация об определенном фильме(задание "фильмотека"). Там есть номер, название, год, страна производства, а как мне отсортировать список по одному из этих полей ? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Сделать процедуру сортировки, использующую функцию сравнения. В функцию сравнения должны передаваться две записи и признак, по какому полю сортировать.

Comment: Немного, неясно, как строится эта процедура сортировки обменом, был бы благодарен за пример

Comment: номер версии delphi был бы весьма уместен.

Comment: @teran десятая версия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 type TMyRec = record
    Name: String[30];
    Age: integer;
 end;

 function Compare(const l, r: TMyRec; key: Integer): Integer;
 begin
    case key of
      0: Result := CompareStr(l.Name, r.Name);
      1: Result := l.Age - r.Age;
    end;
 end;
```

И в процедуре сортировки в месте сравнения вместо `<` используете (key=0 для сравнения по имени, 1 для сравнения по возрасту)

```
procedure Sort(..., key);

 ...
    if Compare(a[i], a[j], key) < 0 then  ...
```

Comment: Так а что, если твой список формируется динамически, а именно с помощью указателей

Comment: Вопрос слишком абстрактный.

Comment: Покажите код, чтобы было ясно, в чём проблема.